# How to obtain country, state, city from reverseGeocodeCoordinate?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding

`GMSReverseGeocodeResponse` contains

```
- (GMSReverseGeocodeResult *)firstResult;
```

whose definition is like:

```
@interface GMSReverseGeocodeResult : NSObject<NSCopying>

/** Returns the first line of the address. */
- (NSString *)addressLine1;

/** Returns the second line of the address. */
- (NSString *)addressLine2;

@end
```

Is there any way to obtain the country, ISO country code, state (administrative_area_1 or corresponding one) from those two strings (valid for *all the countries* and *all the addresses*)?

NOTE: I tried to execute this piece of code

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.4375, -3.6818) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *resp, NSError *error)
 {
    NSLog( @"Error is %@", error) ;
    NSLog( @"%@" , resp.firstResult.addressLine1 ) ;
    NSLog( @"%@" , resp.firstResult.addressLine2 ) ;
 } ] ;
```

But for some reason the handler was never called. I did add the app key, and also added the iOS bundle id to the app key. No error is printed in the console. With this I mean I am not aware of the content of the lines.

Comment: I have opened an request in google maps ios sdk http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4974

Comment: "`GMSGeocoder` now provides structured addresses via `GMSAddress`, deprecating `GMSReverseGeocodeResult`." - [Google Maps SDK for iOS Release Notes, Version 1.7, February 2014](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_17_-_february_2014).

Comment: Yes, it was fixed by Google (almost 1 year later). I just do not know how to close this question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest way is to **upgrade to Version 1.7** of the [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) (released February 2014).
From the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_17_-_february_2014):

> `GMSGeocoder` now provides structured addresses via `GMSAddress`, deprecating `GMSReverseGeocodeResult`.

From [`GMSAddress` Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_address), you can find [these properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_address#properties):

> **`coordinate`**
>   Location, or `kLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` if unknown.
>
> **`thoroughfare`**
>   Street number and name.
>
> **`locality`**
>   Locality or city.
>
> **`subLocality`**
>   Subdivision of locality, district or park.
>
> **`administrativeArea`**
>   Region/State/Administrative area.
>
> **`postalCode`**
>   Postal/Zip code.
>
> **`country`**
>   The country name.
>
> **`lines`**
>   An array of `NSString` containing formatted lines of the address.

No ISO country code though.
Also note that some properties may return `nil`.

Here's a full example:

```m
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.4375, -3.6818) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");
    for(GMSAddress* addressObj in [response results])
    {
        NSLog(@"coordinate.latitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"coordinate.longitude=%f", addressObj.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"thoroughfare=%@", addressObj.thoroughfare);
        NSLog(@"locality=%@", addressObj.locality);
        NSLog(@"subLocality=%@", addressObj.subLocality);
        NSLog(@"administrativeArea=%@", addressObj.administrativeArea);
        NSLog(@"postalCode=%@", addressObj.postalCode);
        NSLog(@"country=%@", addressObj.country);
        NSLog(@"lines=%@", addressObj.lines);
    }
}];
```

and its output:

```
coordinate.latitude=40.437500
coordinate.longitude=-3.681800
thoroughfare=(null)
locality=(null)
subLocality=(null)
administrativeArea=Community of Madrid
postalCode=(null)
country=Spain
lines=(
    "",
    "Community of Madrid, Spain"
)
```

---

Alternatively, you may consider using [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) in the [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-example)).

Answer (score 19):

Answer in **Swift**

Using Google Maps iOS SDK (currently using the V1.9.2 you cannot specify the language in which to return results):

```
@IBAction func googleMapsiOSSDKReverseGeocoding(sender: UIButton) {
    let aGMSGeocoder: GMSGeocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    aGMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude)) {
        (let gmsReverseGeocodeResponse: GMSReverseGeocodeResponse!, let error: NSError!) -> Void in

        let gmsAddress: GMSAddress = gmsReverseGeocodeResponse.firstResult()
        print("\ncoordinate.latitude=\(gmsAddress.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("coordinate.longitude=\(gmsAddress.coordinate.longitude)")
        print("thoroughfare=\(gmsAddress.thoroughfare)")
        print("locality=\(gmsAddress.locality)")
        print("subLocality=\(gmsAddress.subLocality)")
        print("administrativeArea=\(gmsAddress.administrativeArea)")
        print("postalCode=\(gmsAddress.postalCode)")
        print("country=\(gmsAddress.country)")
        print("lines=\(gmsAddress.lines)")
    }
}
```

Using Google Reverse Geocoding API V3 (currently you can [specify](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) the language in which to return results):

```
@IBAction func googleMapsWebServiceGeocodingAPI(sender: UIButton) {
    self.callGoogleReverseGeocodingWebservice(self.currentUserLocation())
}

// #1 - Get the current user's location (latitude, longitude).
private func currentUserLocation() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    // returns current user's location. 
}

// #2 - Call Google Reverse Geocoding Web Service using AFNetworking.
private func callGoogleReverseGeocodingWebservice(let userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(userLocation.latitude),\(userLocation.longitude)&key=\(self.googleMapsiOSAPIKey)&language=\(self.googleReverseGeocodingWebserviceOutputLanguageCode)&result_type=country"

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager().GET(
        url,
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("GET user's country request succeeded !!!\n")

            // The goal here was only for me to get the user's iso country code + 
            // the user's Country in english language.
            if let responseObject: AnyObject = responseObject {
                println("responseObject:\n\n\(responseObject)\n\n")
                let rootDictionary = responseObject as! NSDictionary
                if let results = rootDictionary["results"] as? NSArray {
                    if let firstResult = results[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let addressComponents = firstResult["address_components"] as? NSArray {
                            if let firstAddressComponent = addressComponents[0] as? NSDictionary {
                                if let longName = firstAddressComponent["long_name"] as? String {
                                    println("long_name: \(longName)")
                                }
                                if let shortName = firstAddressComponent["short_name"] as? String {
                                    println("short_name: \(shortName)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            println("Error GET user's country request: \(error.localizedDescription)\n")
            println("Error GET user's country request: \(operation.responseString)\n")
        }
    )

}
```

I hope this code snippet and explanation will help future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 version for addresses in the United States:

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSAddress {

    var formattedAddress: String {
        let addressComponents = [
            thoroughfare,        // One Infinite Loop
            locality,            // Cupertino
            administrativeArea,  // California
            postalCode           // 95014
        ]
        return addressComponents
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .joined(separator: ", ")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4.0 the func gets CLLocation and return postal address

```
  func geocodeCoordinates(location : CLLocation)->String{
         var postalAddress  = ""
        let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(location.coordinate, completionHandler: {response,error in
            if let gmsAddress = response!.firstResult(){
                for line in  gmsAddress.lines! {
                    postalAddress += line + " "
                }
               return postalAddress
            }
        })
        return ""
    }
```