# Get human readable address using Google maps iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing an iOS app which integrates `google maps iOS sdk` . 
In my `GMSMapView` I have dropped a GMSMarker, I want to set the title of the marker with location name . I have tried `GMSAddress`, `GMSGeocoder` and `GMSReverseGeocodeResult` but I could not get the exact location name. How can get the complete address of the current location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21819559

Comment: @TonyMkenu I have already tried those

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036007/how-to-obtain-country-state-city-from-reversegeocodecoordinate) should have what you're after. Basically upgrade to v1.7 and use `GMSAddress`
The linked post includes a code sample you can use as well.