# How to get nearest human readable address from GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate with nil response

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding

In my iOS app I want to let user to pick an address with a long press gesture on a `GMSMapView`. So I implemented the `mapView:_ didLongPressAtCoordinate:_` method to take the coordinate he choose and to make reverseGeocoding and get the address:

```
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
            // Everything ok
        } else {
            // Here the response is 'nil'
        }
    }
```

What can I can do here, when the response is `nil` to get the nearest location coordinate with a human readable address?

Comment: Kindly provide log for errors

Comment: There's no error. <code>error</code> var is nil. Simply, <code>response</code> is nil too.

Comment: Have you checked the logs if you are getting coordinates when doing the `mapView: _ didLongPressAtCoordinate:_`?

Comment: If not, here I found an existing SO question for [how to get the touch location on map] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685918/how-to-get-the-latitude-longitude-of-a-touch-location-on-mapview-using-google?lq=1). I hope this helps

Comment: Yes. The location coordinate is valid. The problem is when the user made a long tap on the sea, as example. There's no valid address in there and I want to get the nearest address.