# How to use Google GMSGeocoder on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, google-geocoder

I couldn't find any piece of code or any tutorial for using geocoding on MKMapView. Is there anyone to guide me about my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to obtain country, state, city from reverseGeocodeCoordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036007/how-to-obtain-country-state-city-from-reversegeocodecoordinate)
or
http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

take a look at this example hope it can help you.